# CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE does not make any changes in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

```
   cap.open(0);
   cap.set(CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB, 0);
   cap.set(CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE, 10);
```

I tried to set the WhiteBalance above but the capture is not changing whatever I write to the temperature. Am I missing something?

I read from several forums that some properties have to be in a certain interval. Like `CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE` should expect two values: 0.75 auto exposure **On** and 0.25 as auto exposure **OFF.** Once you set auto exposure Off with 0.25 then set exposure to any value that you desire. But I did not see a similar thing for wb temperature.

**Note:**

Camera Model: DFM 27UR0135-ML - USB 3.0 color board camera

I don't think it doesn't support balance settings, because the code below was working:

```
//WhiteBalance
Ptr<xphoto::WhiteBalancer> wb;
wb = xphoto::createLearningBasedWB();
wb ->balanceWhite(frame, frame);
```

But I didnt get good results with automatic white balancing, that's why I want to change the parameters like temperature, red, blue manually.

Comment: Perhaps your capture device doesn't support white balance settings?

Comment: It was working when I was trying to autobalance using these codes: Ptr<xphoto::WhiteBalancer> wb;    wb = xphoto::createLearningBasedWB(); wb ->balanceWhite(frame, frame); But I dont want automatic balance

Comment: I think your autoWB is not computed on the camera but in your application.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da280eb4a13368f5ccdea3b2233dbc25b6) says: *Reading / writing properties involves many layers. Some unexpected result might happens along this chain. Effective behaviour depends from device hardware, driver and API Backend.*

Comment: its better to use device api, instead opencv backend

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/white-balance-the-camera-capture-on-opencv-c/5834

Answer (score 0):

Auto white balance is OFF at value `1` and ON at value `3`.
`cap.set(CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB, 1);`